# Static member accessability through generic inheritance

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, static, protected

I was recently coming up with some rather funky singleton work and discovered that I can access a protected static member from any unique inherited type using the same base of inheritance where generics are used. An example of what I'm talking about is as follows:

```
public abstract class Class<T>
{
    protected static int number = 5;

    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(number);
    }
}

public class ClassA : Class<ClassA>
{
}

public class ClassB : Class<ClassB>
{
    public ClassB()
    {
        number = 1;
    }
}

public class ClassC : Class<ClassC>
{
    public ClassC()
    {
        number = ClassA.number;//I don't want to be able to see "number"
    }
}
```

Since generics are in use here, each unique inheriting type gets its own "number" (which is what I want). But I don't like that I can access "number" from other types inheriting the same base type when generics are used. Is there a way to fix this? And also why does this happen (I understand why it happens with inheritance without generics, but it doesn't seem right that it happens with generics)?

Comment: Usually it is bad practice to have a static protected variable. The usual use case of a static method/variable is so that the variable/method is accessible without needing to instantiate an object. Making something protected or private seems odd in this case. What's your use case, if you don't mind my asking?

Comment: You could make the static field private, and then implement protected instance methods in your abstract class to get/set the value of this static field (or use an equivalent protected property). This way, instances of ClassB cannot acces the static field of ClassA...

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto No it is relevant because a `static` variable in a generic class is only unique for a given set of generic types.  That is you can change the value of `Class<ClassA>.number` but that will not change the value of `Class<ClassB>.number` because `Class<ClassA>` and `Class<ClassB>` are seen as two unique types.

Comment: @juharr Huh, we learn something new every day. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I don't like that I can access "number" from other classes inheriting the same base class when generics are used. Is there a way to fix this?

The only true fix is to declare separate `private static` variables for each class. This will keep you from being able see the number variable in one class type from any other class type.

```
public abstract class Class<T>
{
    private static int number = 5;

    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(number);
    }
}

public class ClassA : Class<ClassA>
{
}

public class ClassB : Class<ClassB>
{
    private static int number;

    public ClassB()
    {
        number = 1;
    }
}

public class ClassC : Class<ClassC>
{
    private static int number;

    public ClassC()
    {
        number = 123; // Cannot see ClassA.number because it is private to `Class<T>`
    }
}
```

The side effect is being caused by declaring the variable `protected static` and using it with inheritance. It is unclear why you would attempt to do that when the behavior you are after is that of a `private static` field.

Comment: "If that is what you want, you have failed to achieve it."?

number = ClassA.number; ClassC's number and ClassA's number are two different variables... They have their own "number". Maybe I could clarify that each unique inheriting Type gets its own "number" variable.

Comment: Ahh, okay I ran a test and you are right - you have different class types so you get a different variable per class. It is still the same variable for all instances.

Answer (score -3):

You can use the [private](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/private) modifier to make the static member invisible to descendents. Use protected only if you want the descendants to be able to access it. It makes no difference generic vs. non.

```
public abstract class Class<T>
{
    private static int number = 5;  //Private now

    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(number);  //Works
    }
}

public class ClassA : Class<ClassA>
{
    //No number
}

public class ClassB : Class<ClassB>
{
    public ClassB()
    {
        number = 1;  //Will not compile
    }
}

public class ClassC : Class<ClassC>
{
    public ClassC()
    {
        number = ClassA.number;//Will not compile
    }
}
```

If you want the static variable to be accessible only to some descendants and not others, define the variable in the first class in the inheritance chain that needs access:

```
public abstract class Class<T>
{
}

public class ClassA : Class<ClassA>
{
    static private int number = 7;
}

public class ClassB : Class<ClassB>
{
    static private int number = 7;

    public ClassB()
    {
        ClassA.number = 5;  //Does not compile
        ClassB.number = 6;
    }
}

public class ClassC : Class<ClassC>
{
    static private int number = 7;

    public ClassC()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ClassA.number);  //Does not compile
        Console.WriteLine(ClassB.number);  //Does not compile
        Console.WriteLine(ClassC.number);  //Compiles
    }
}
```

You cannot define something in an ancestor class and remove it from a descendant.

Comment: It cannot be private, as ClassB would still need to access it. e.g. only direct inheritors should be able to access the variable.

Comment: I guess it doesn't fits. Looks like he wants to be able to access the `ClassC`'s `number` and not to be able to access the `ClassA`'s `number` (I'm downvoter)

Comment: I see. I've amended my answer to accommodate.